# Understanding Cordova's Browser platform

Tags: cordova, browser, deployment

I've coddled together an app that can be viewed here.
[Spherical Resonator Designer](http://spheres.ml)

The javascript in the app doesn't work properly if not served.
Building for android, the app had the same issue.
So I used the Browser platform to build within Cordova.
When I run the build with Browser at the cli,
I see that node.js starts as a static file server,
the configured browser opens (chrome), and the app works fine.
How do I deploy a Browser app?
Unlike an apk for android, I don't know what to do with the build
at this point.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova you can add the platforms that you want to target:
`$ cordova platform add android`
But before that there is some other requirement that you need to have installed, like Android SDK and JDK, Gradle and setting the environment variables.
Just follow these steps: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have cordova setup and have added Browser as a platform. the Browser build went okay and i can run it from cli. i don't understand what to do with the build as far as deployment.

Comment: Hello, again. Just to be in the same page, Do you want to deploy it for browser or for android?

Comment: i prefer android and created an apk before i created a build for browser. the issue is part of the app doesn't work unless it is being served from a server. so that apk didn't work right. i tried the browser platform though now i don't think it will make a difference. regarding the browser platform, from what i see, the build just copied my app and added a number of files in and around it. what do i do with the build? it is meant for a server? what are the extra files for? i don't think i understand browser.